# How do I create a more efficient version of this?

Tags: java

I just barely started studying Java. Most of my knowledge is with Python and html/css. I wanted to practice by taking an example from my job to create an automated counting system. Basically solar panels are hooked up to "inverters" and each inverter type can only hold up to a certain amount of solar panels (modules). 3800h inverter can hold up to 18 - if it's over that, we'll need to use a 7600h inverter which can hold up to 37. I created a really redundant text version for this and the main goal was to split up the modules evenly between two inverters if I had more than a 10000h inverter could hold. Basically split the number of modules between two 7600h inverters.

Does anyone have any pointers/ideas for a better less redundant equation? Rather than all the if/else if lines? Maybe even better variable storage? I'm obviously a beginner so the answer could very well be the easiest thing I just wouldn't know where to start. Thanks for any input.

```
class autoInverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int moduleCount = 53;
        int moduleRemainder;
        int secondInverter;

        int se3800hMax = 18;
        int se7600hMax = 37;
        int se10000hMax = 49;

        String se3800h = "SE300H Inverter";
        String se7600h = "SE7600H Inverter";
        String se10000h = "SE10000H Inverter";

        System.out.println("Total modules: " + moduleCount);

        if (moduleCount <= se3800hMax) {
            System.out.println(se3800h + ": " + moduleCount + " modules");
        } else if (moduleCount <= se7600hMax) {
            System.out.println(se7600h + ": " + moduleCount + " modules");
        } else if (moduleCount <= se10000hMax) {
            System.out.println(se10000h + ": " + moduleCount + " modules");
        } else if (moduleCount > se7600hMax * 2) {
            moduleRemainder = moduleCount % 2;
            secondInverter = moduleCount / 2 + moduleRemainder;
            System.out.println(se10000h + ": " + moduleCount / 2 + " modules");
            System.out.println(se10000h + ": " + secondInverter + " modules");
        } else if (moduleCount > se10000hMax) {
            moduleRemainder = moduleCount % 2;
            secondInverter = moduleCount / 2 + moduleRemainder;
            System.out.println(se7600h + ": " + moduleCount / 2 + " modules");
            System.out.println(se7600h + ": " + secondInverter + " modules");
        }


    }
}
```

---

This would print out:

Total modules: 53

SE7600H Inverter: 26 modules

SE7600H Inverter: 27 modules

Comment: Unless you have a need to make it more modular (The ability to drop in new cases like more than two inverters or different inverter sizes)  this is likely to be the simplest way to code what you are trying to do.  If not, you might be able to gain flexibility by looping and subtracting sizes.  For instance, would it help to know that 40 modules could be handled by one 3800 and one 7600,  or do you always have to install matched inverters?

Comment: This is a simple attempt at it, yeah. You can use 3800 and 7600 together (though it's preferable to use matching inverters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created an "Inverter" class that had a numberOfModules and price, you could probably create a "Best Fit" algorithm that looped over them and chose the minimum price for a given number of inverters--but I'm guessing that's overkill.  I think what you have is probably the easiest to read and maintain (The most important aspect of most code).

If you just wanted to make your existing solution more modular, you could create something more simplified...

Create a group of 5 "Solution" objects.  Each solution has a max number of modules it can handle and the inverter configuration that can handle them.  Iterate over these solutions until you come up with one big enough to handle your current number of modules.

You will then have the number and type of inverters available, so just divide the modules among them (Rather than just coding 1 or 2, I would figure out a way to divide the modules among n inverters, for future expandability.)

Does that make sense?  The 5 solution objects can be created from a text configuration file so that you can easily add a new solution without rebuilding.

Comment: Thanks, i like your idea :)

Answer (score 0):

"Efficient" is a very loose term. If you mean performance, I think it's fine. If you mean modularity, then I would do something like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InverterFactory factory = new InverterFactory();
        CountingSystem countingSystem = new CountingSystem(53);
        Inverter myInverter = factory.create("SE300H");

        countingSystem.calculate(myInverter);

    }
}
```

---

```
public class InverterFactory {

    public static Inverter create(String inverterType) {

        if (inverterType.equals("SE300H")) {
            return new InverterTypeA();
        } else if (inverterType.equals("SE7600H")) {
            return new InverterTypeB();
        } else if (inverterType.equals("SE1000H")) {
            return new InverterTypeC();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface Inverter {
}
```

---

```
public class InverterTypeA implements Inverter {

    private final int max;

    public InverterTypeA() {
        this.max = 18;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return this.max;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SE300H Inverter";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CountingSystem {

    private final int moduleCount;

    public CountingSystem(int moduleCount) {
        this.moduleCount = moduleCount;
    }

    public void calculate(Inverter inverter) {

        if (moduleCount  <= inverter.getMax()) {
            System.out.println(inverter.toString() + ": " + moduleCount + " modules");
        }
        //etc
    }
}
```

Obviously the method/class names should be changed for whatever makes sense in your use case. Also, 3 different types of Inverter classes might be overkill, but it does make your code more scalable in case you need to add more types in the future; the factory also makes it easier to test.

Comment: Thank you, this is something I could definitely look at.